# slapcat doesn't dump the full iredmail database

Tags: backup, email-server, openldap

i installed iredmail http://www.iredmail.org/ with the ldap backend and entered some userdata afterwards i tried to add some data via phpldapadmin, which does not worked (tired to export a user, add more "shadow emails" and reimport it; got an duplicate entry error; i just mention it for information, it is not the main problem here).

my main problem:
i want to backup the ldap database, so i tried to use the backupscipts shiped with iredmail but not the whole data gets backed up. as far as i understand only the two root nodes of the ldap database gets dumped. 
i have seen that slapcat is used for the backup, on the command line slapcat also returns not enough data.

phpldapadmin and the command 'ldapsearch -LLL -Wx -D "cn=Manager,dc=mail,dc=domain,dc=com"' return the correct data (i can't verify that every field needed is dumped, but all email user get dumped)

dumped data:

```
dn: dc=mydomain,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organizcomion
o: mydomain.com
dc: mydomain
structuralObjectClass: organizcomion
entryUUID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
crecomorsName: cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com
crecomeTimestamp: 20110323043759Z
entryCSN: 20110323043759.391623Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com
modifyTimestamp: 20110323043759Z

dn: cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizcomionalRole
cn: admin
description: LDAP administrcomor
userPassword:: passwordhash
structuralObjectClass: organizcomionalRole
entryUUID: yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
crecomorsName: cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com
crecomeTimestamp: 20110323043759Z
entryCSN: 20110323043759.395618Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com
modifyTimestamp: 20110323043759Z
```

link to iredmail forum post
http://www.iredmail.org/forum/topic1990-problem-ldap-backup-dont-work.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on my iredmail installation on debian it was nessesary to define the ldap config explicit

```
  slapcat -f /path/to/slapd.conf
```